# Nullable reference in JSON does noet become null when PUT request

Tags: json, .net, put, rest

I am making a rest API on my exercise, and I have chosen for a very simple approach, I have three entities: Chapter, Theme, Priority. One chapter may have 0 or 1 theme and 0 or 1 priority.

So they are looking like this in JSON format.

CHAPTER:

```
    {
      "id": 4,
      "title": "De centrale limietstelling",
      "isFinished": false,
      "priority": {
          "id": 1,
          "title": "Zeer belangerijk zeker instuderen",
          "color": "#F1128D"
    },
      "theme": {
          "id": 1,
          "title": "Onderzoekstechnieken"
      },
      "date": null
    }
```

THEME:

```
    {
      "id": 2,
       "title": "Ontwerpen 3"
    }
```

PRIORITY:

```
    {
      "id": 1,
      "title": "Zeer belangerijk zeker instuderen",
      "color": "#F1128D"
    }
```

I can delete priority and then in the Chapter the priorities of this id are set to null as expected.

but when i edit any chapter with PUT request and set for example Theme to null:

```
{
  "id": 4,
  "title": "De centrale limietstelling",
  "isFinished": false,
  "priority": null,
  "theme": null,
  "date": null
}
```

have a 204 responce.

but when i open these chapter again i see that priority and theme are not set to null, but remain th e same as it was.

to clarify my entities these are the code of chapter, theme and prio:

```cs
public class Chapter
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public bool IsFinished { get; set; }
        public Priority? Priority { get; set; }
        public Theme? Theme { get; set; }
        public DateTime? Date { get; set; }

        public Chapter()
        {
            IsFinished = false;
        }
    }
```

```cs
public class Theme
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }

    }
```

```cs
public class Priority
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Color { get; set; }

    }
```

I Also need to make use of DTO:

```cs
public class ChapterDTO
    {
        [Required]
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public Priority? Priority { get; set; }
        public Theme? Theme { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime? Date { get; set; }

        public ChapterDTO()
        {

        }
    }
```

```cs
public class PriorityDTO
    {
        [Required]
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Color { get; set; }
    }
```

```cs
public class ThemeDTO
    {
        [Required]
        public string Title { get; set; }
    }
```

And this is my mapping to DB

```cs
 protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
           base.OnModelCreating(builder);
           builder.Entity<Chapter>().HasOne(e => e.Priority).WithMany().OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.SetNull).IsRequired(false);
           builder.Entity<Chapter>().HasOne(e => e.Theme).WithMany().OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.SetNull).IsRequired(false);
        }
```

how do I make it possible to store the null reference to theme and subject in Chapter?

Kind regard, ilya